# Does the Ruby method lookup start from the bottom of a class and go up, or from the top and go down?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm starting to learn more about the Ruby object model, and am trying to understand the flow of how methods are found.

As I understand it, an object searches for a method by checking it's self class (going to the right) and if the method is not found there, it goes up the ancestor hierarchy.

What I'm confused about though is... when it looks into a class, does it read each method from the bottom up, or from the top down?

I'm thinking the former.  But if that's true, then it strikes me as counterintuitive to what I've always understood about how programs are read/interpreted -- from the top down.

Can someone confirm my understanding of this.  Thanks.

Comment: Ruby does execute from the top down, including method declarations. There can only be one method with a given name, so as the answer states, later declarations override earlier ones. When a method is called, there is no "top down"/"bottom up", there is only "do I have this method or do I need to keep looking?"

Comment: Yes, but the interpreter does read from the top down in terms of procedural mechanics.  If a method with the same name is found, it returns the last method.  This is how I understood the answer.

Comment: They's what I said. But the class is not read every time a method is called, it's read once at file load time.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That is a subtle, but helpful point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

later declarations override earlier ones -

```
class Foo
  def hello
    'hello first'
  end

  def hello
    'hello second'
  end
end

f = Foo.new

puts f.hello # hello second
```

Comment: Oh, that's such a better way of articulating it.  Thank you.